# How would I hook Trac up to multiple repositories?

Tags: svn, trac

How would I hook Trac up to multiple repositories?

In this case I don't want to use the ticketing system or the wiki, simply connect it to browse multiple repos.

I would think it would be as easy as having a script update the repository link in its conf.ini file every time you wanted to look at a new repo, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's been [much talk](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects/MultipleEnvironments) about doing this but currently it's [unsupported](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/2086) by Trac.

You would need to make multiple instances of Trac, one for each repository. You can't just change the configuration file as Trac stores a bunch of information about the repository in its database and doing that would break it.

Comment: Trac 0.12 will support multiple repositories and it is close to being released.

Comment: Trac v1 supports this.

Answer (score 3):

I think from 0.12 trac will support multiple repositories in one trac project:
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.12/TracRepositoryAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use one of the various trac alternatives such as Redmine or DrProject or (if I may pimp myself) piano-man.

Comment: +1 for redmine, I've used it in the past and it was extremely good.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to browse the repositories, you may want to use WebSVN.

You can setup Trac so that it has one trac-wiki per repository. To my knowledge, it exactly is one trac-wiki per repository, though, and under a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I stopped using TRAC is this particular problem.